# Geometry nodes, how to create dimension for every edge separately

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to create dimension per edge.
I think it's possible by repeat zone.
(edges count is not fixed)
any ideas?

[image]

**desired result:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the last "Join Geometry", and remove the beginning that separates a single edge:

[image]

Then you can name it "Your Logic", create a new node tree, and insert the previous node tree inside a *Repeat Zone*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank u Markus  